# Type 'Moment' is not assignable to type 'Date'. Property 'toDateString' is missing in type 'Moment'

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

I have configure moment with my angular2 application, and when i tried to assign the date of this week saturday to a date type variable,

```
  case "weekend":         
        this.fromDate =  moment().startOf('week');
```

It shows an error saying,

```
Type 'Moment' is not assignable to type 'Date'.   Property 'toDateString' is missing in type 'Moment'
```

I have imported moment in my component as follows,

```
import * as moment from 'moment/moment';
```

Comment: why downvote here?

Comment: The message is self-explanatory. You're trying to assign `moment().startOf('week')`, which is of type `Moment`, to the variable `this.fromDate`, which is of type `Date`. Set the type of `this.fromDate`to Moment, or transform the moment to a Date.

Comment: `startOf` returns a moment object use [`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) if you need to convert to js Date.

Comment: @VincenzoC thanks man, i thought there is some issue wiht the import

Comment: @Sajeetharan glad to help, so using `toDate()` solves your issue? I'm not sure if I have to post it as an answer or you are going to delete this question.

Comment: @VincenzoC i need to run and check ! but it solved the issue in IDE. surely i will mark as answer

Comment: @JBNizet please post as answer

Comment: The type of moment function results seem often moment.Moment

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`startOf`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/):

> Mutates the original moment by setting it to the start of a unit of time

so it returns a moment object. Use [`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) if you need to convert to JavaScript Date.

```
case "weekend":         
    this.fromDate =  moment().startOf('week').toDate();
```

Comment: Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Comment: @StanleyMohlala so probably your case is different from the one of the the question in which error was "_Type 'Moment' is not assignable to type 'Date'_". I think that left part of the assignment in your code is `ReactNode` object, feel free to ask a new question providing a [mcve] to reproduce your issue